# Order of the width of a peak in perturbation methods

Tags: laplace-transform, perturbation-theory, laplace-method

My question relates to this excerpt from page 63 of the [lecture notes](http://pordlabs.ucsd.edu/wryoung/SIO203C2015/PerturbationNotes11.pdf) on perturbation methods by W.R. Young.

How does the author find the 'width of the peak' to be $s^{-3/4}$ in this example? I have never come across this expression before and have no idea how the 'width' of a peak is defined mathematically here. Some help would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.nbi.dk/~polesen/borel/node13.html#start) is another explanation of the  "saddle point method". The idea is that the integral is approximated by a Gaussian whose width  is a function of the second order coefficient in a Taylor expansion of the exponent (eqn. 126).